# Knockout in IE8 calls the subscribe binding on select automatically?

Tags: knockout.js, internet-explorer-8

I am binding an array to dropdownlist using Knockout, and subscribing to this dropdown value selection ("chosenResult")

```
<select data-bind="options: arrayResult, optionsText: 'item', selectedOptions: chosenResult, multiple: false, optionsCaption: 'Choose'"></select>
```

Now IE8 automatically calls this subscription for the first time and selects first value from dropdownlist. All other browsers (chrome, firefox) are working fine and only call this subscription function when user selects a value.

Not sure why it is only happening in IE8.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't test this as I now longer have access to an IE8 instance.  But if this is a single select you should use `value` not `selectedOptions`

Comment: I have windows 7 with ie 10 and problem can be replicated by switching to ie 8 mode from developers tool. Unfortunately this is a multiselect. The problem is occurring on win xp with ie 8 as well.

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1 and IE 11.  I can no longer specify compatibility mode!  Did you change the selectedOptions to value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

The reason for subscribed function being called in IE was that the items in the array bound to select list was being added in a loop, which was calling notificatinos everytime an item was added into "arrayResult" array. The way I fixed it was that first create the array and then add that array into observable array. Strange thing is that such issue wasn't experienced in firefox or chrome though.